# Grails - Parameter in a Quartz job Trigger

Tags: grails, parameters, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger, multitrigger

I have the following quartz job, set via Quartz-plugin:

```
class UserMonthlyNotificationJob { 
static triggers = {
        cron name:'dailyTrigger', cronExpression: " ... "
        cron name:'weeklyTrigger', cronExpression: " ... "
        cron name:'monthlyTrigger', cronExpression: " ... "
}

    def execute(){ ... }
}
```

I would like to be able to set a parameter in the trigger that would be available in the `execute` block. 
It seems I can not set any variable in a `cron trigger`, and a `custom trigger` require to implement the `Quartz Trigger interface`, which I do not know how to do.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your job implement [StatefulJob](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/StatefulJob.html), then you'll have access to [JobExecutionContext](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html) which has a [Trigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/Trigger.html) instance accessor. If you have your own Trigger class, that will be an instance of it.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much, it did the trick. This is how I ended up using it:

```
import org.quartz.StatefulJob
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext

class UserPeriodicalNotificationJob implements StatefulJob{   

    static triggers = {
        cron name:'dailyTrigger', cronExpression: ConfigHolder.config.userDailyNotificationJob
        cron name:'weeklyTrigger', cronExpression: ConfigHolder.config.userWeeklyNotificationJob
        cron name:'monthlyTrigger', cronExpression: ConfigHolder.config.userMonthlyNotificationJob   
    }

    void execute(JobExecutionContext context){
        def triggerName = context.trigger.key
        try {
            switch (triggerName) {...}
        }
        catch(Exception) {...}
  }
}
```